# Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've looked through all the other questions but somehow think mine is unique

I get this error. It does connect to the database, as it does return results but I get errors like these.

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user '******'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/*******/public_html/********/*******/module-initialize.php on line 15

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/*******/public_html/********/********/module-initialize.php on line 16
```

I removed the real url for security reasons. and the code in the region for that error is

```
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
// make data query-safe
$_GET = safe_data($_GET, 'query');
```

Comment: your Database username and password doesn't match. Please check it

Comment: Hi, you might be using incorrect username and password. Please check again.

Comment: Your connection is not obtained by `mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);`. check user name and password

Comment: Have you tried checking the username and password? Also, check the username and password.

Comment: You have to fix the erros step by step...1-`Access denied for user '******'` check your user or password

Comment: Thank you guys. That helped. Script has 2 config.php files to connect to database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database login credentials must not be accurate.

"mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given" implies that you're passing either true or false via the $link variable below:

```
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
```

Since mysql_connect() either returns a resource or boolean false for $link, that implies either $dbhost, $dbuser, or $dbpass is null or invalid somehow.

Comment: can add `mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('not connected');`

Comment: Okay, the script has 2 config.php files, one for admin and 1 for front-end (WHO DOES THAT?)

I only entered details in one. Thanks you.

Comment: @Anton Yeah, that's annoying...  Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

**Access denied for user** :- Please check username and password.
**mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource**. because no link created by mysql_connect that's why this error showing

Answer (score 1):

You have not created connection.

To create connection use this

```
$dbconn = mysql_connect("host=localhost user=username password=password")
    or die('Could not connect: ' .  mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($database_name, $dbconn );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Username, password and your Database server address.
The warning is self explanatory

Comment: Not self explanatory if youre a graphic designer. Ha ha :-) But thank you for answer.

Comment: lol, I understand. Try logging in to MySQL server from command line or from a DB administrator and check your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

try something as:

```
$con=mysql_connect("server", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
```

it will help you to know the root couse of problem...for more see [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

and know about [die()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) , where and how to use it for track error in coding

add try to use now mysqli_* function instead of mysql_* function

Answer (score -1):

Add a `boolean`, that worked for me:

```
$con = mysql_connect("server", "username", "password", false) or die(mysql_error());
//                                     Boolean goes here ^
```